# multiMonthYear and validRange option

Tags: view, fullcalendar

I've run into an issue where FullCalendar will stop working if I am using the "multiMonthYear" view in combination with ValidRange option.

See following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sauron-dev/pen/xxQGoMe)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    initialDate: "2023-05-07",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,multiMonthYear"
    },
    validRange: {
      start: "2023-04-01",
      end: "2024-03-31"
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: "All Day Event",
        start: "2023-05-01"
      },
      {
        title: "Long Event",
        start: "2023-05-07",
        end: "2023-05-10"
      },
      {
        groupId: "999",
        title: "Repeating Event",
        start: "2023-05-09T16:00:00"
      },
      {
        groupId: "999",
        title: "Repeating Event",
        start: "2023-05-16T16:00:00"
      },
      {
        title: "Conference",
        start: "2023-05-11",
        end: "2023-05-13"
      },
      {
        title: "Meeting",
        start: "2023-05-12T10:30:00",
        end: "2023-05-12T12:30:00"
      },
      {
        title: "Lunch",
        start: "2023-05-12T12:00:00"
      },
      {
        title: "Meeting",
        start: "2023-05-12T14:30:00"
      },
      {
        title: "Birthday Party",
        start: "2023-05-13T07:00:00"
      },
      {
        title: "Click for Google",
        url: "http://google.com/",
        start: "2023-05-28"
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

If you have the validRange option the view "year" (multiMonthYear) is not selectable it will not load. If you comment that out it will work.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it produces some console errors. I suggest you report it via the documented process: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . At stackoverflow we can help you with configuring and integrating the calendar in your applications, but we cannot do anything with internal issues within fullCalendar itself - no-one from the project monitors this site as far as I know. Thanks.